# Quintology or Pentalogy?

Tags: differences, nouns, latin, compounds, greek

Recently I was looking at the X-Men box set and saw that currently five have been released.

I had it in my head that these would be called a *quintology* but I have seen them being called a *pentalogy*.

I assume both words are interchangeable, but is one of the terms preferred over the other, or is it a matter of taste?

Comment: I've heard 'a trilogy in five parts'...http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hitch-Hikers-Guide-Galaxy-Trilogy/dp/0434003484 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Pentalogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentalogy)* is the "correct" (as these things go) term. It comes from *penta* + *logy* which are both Greek. *Quintology*, on the other hand, is a mixture of Latin and Greek roots, a practice which is not [linguistically kosher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word). Similarly, it should be *tetralogy* rather than *quadrilogy*.

Comment: "Television? No good will come of it. A bastard word, half Greek, half Latin." (C P Scott, usually quoted with three words omitted).

Comment: I assume the term pentuple would be used instead of quintuple as well?

Comment: In the case of _quintuple_, you have two Latin roots: _quintus_ (five) and _plus_ (fold), although Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary points out that _plus_ is akin to both the Latin word _plenum_ (full) and the Greek word _pleion_ (more).

Comment: @SvenYargs: the Latin for -fold is actually *-plex*, as in *triplex* and *quintuplex*

Answer (score 2):

*Pentad* and *quincunx* could also be used. The latter more often describes a pattern with five coplanar points, such as ones found on dominoes or dice.