# A Latin word that is like the word "trinity" but for "five fold" or "five as one"

Tags: single-word-requests, latin, attributive-nouns

I read that the word "trinity", a Latin based word, literally translates as "three fold" or more specifically "three as one". That being the case, what Latin based word would I use to express, "five fold" or "five as one"?

Notes: I found a similar question on this site but it had been closed as, "unlikely anyone would be interested in this". Apparently, that is NOT the case. :)

More Notes: I am only asking about the word "trinity". I am in no way interested in the "Holy Trinity", so aggressive Christians need not respond. :)

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence?  The Latin root "quint-" is what you want, but there is no direct analog to "trinity."  "quintipartite" means "divided into five parts," but "tripartite" is also a word and doesn't mean the same thing as "trinity."  Note: "Penta-" is similar, but a borrowing from Greek.

Comment: Consider the (open) questions https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170967/hypernym-of-pair-dyad-tetrad-pentad and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106314/quintology-or-pentalogy/114236#114236  which suggest *pentad* and *quincunx*, among other ideas.

Comment: Do you just mean a group of five? If so, is there some reason that neither *quintet* nor *cinquain*  works for you?

Comment: Note: the word that actually means ‘three-fold’ word is ***triple(x)***, not _trinity_, which really just means ‘threeness’.

Comment: Thanks so much for reposting this question - this is *exactly* the question I have today :)

Comment: For me, the word trinity in English is "overdetermined" by the religious connotation. two-fold, three-fold, four-fold, five-fold, six-fold, etc.....are generally the adjectives one sees here and there...By the way, it's **three-in-one**, not "three as one". What context are you using this word in?

Comment: There are words for different numbers of gods, such as ennead (9, generally of ancient Egyptian myth), and a wide range of words for groups of different sizes, some of quite specific meanings - four has tetrad (mainly in biology), quartet (music), four-piece (popular music), tetralogy (which has medical uses as well as literary), square, quatrain, and other terms. Hence it depends what it is a group of.

Answer (score 7):

**[Quincunx](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quincunx)** is not exactly what you asked for, but it can be pretty close when used in a very slightly metaphorical sense:

> an arrangement of five objects, as trees, in a square or rectangle, one at each corner and one in the middle.

It all depends on how you would use it exactly. In the slightly metaphorical/loose sense, you could say something like this:

> In the middle of the floor, a quincunx of formidable ladies were overseeing arrangements.

It would not be too far an extension to speak of a quincunx of major deities in a certain religion.

A somewhat less poetic term is **quintet**, which can be basically a group of five elements/people.

Edit: I see Rob's excellent comment above now. I would say **pentad** is also an excellent choice, which is like  *triad* and has a meaning very similar to *trinity*.

*Pentalogy* is a nice word, but it only applies to *logoi*, i.e. words, theories, literature and the like. *Quintology* would be an unnecessary hybrid of Latin and Greek.

Tchrist's *cinquain* is aequally nice. I suppose it would be a metaphor, though, because it is normally restricted to a group of five verses (lines in a poem).

P.S. I really think three is much better. Who would find five heads convenient?

Comment: I don't get it. You meant to write _aequally_? (Sorry if it's something super obvious that I'm missing.)

Comment: @Heartspring: Yes, I like that spelling, if you don't mind. Your other edit I was happy with.

Comment: Oh, I see. I assumed it was a typo, sorry I didn't realize. (I don't mind at all; I hope you'll forgive my ignorantly changing it!)

Comment: @Heartspring: Don't worry, nothing wrong with well-meaning edits; after all, it's easy enough for the poster to reverse them if he doesn't like them.

Answer (score 3):

What about ***[penta-](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/penta-)***   from Greek and used in Latin:

> a combining form occurring in loanwords from Greek, meaning “five” ( Pentateuch); on this model, used in the formation of compound words ( pentavalent).

Answer (score 3):

A *[trinity](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/trinity)* can still just mean three of something — the Christian doctrine of the Trinity is an assigned meaning rather than one inherent in the word. The three-in-oneness of the Godhead is expressed in *[triune](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/triune)*. Sometimes Latin derivatives don't want to count past three: primary, secondary, tertiary; or even purely English once, twice, thrice, but a five-member brass ensemble is a quintet, and five infants born at the same time to one mother — a different form of the five-in-one you seek — are quintuplets.

This would suggest *quintity*, as it did to the members of the German brass quintet [Quintity.](https://de-de.facebook.com/quintitybrass/) Though the word hasn't made it into any dictionary to designate five of something, it would still be understood. *Quintune*, however, would be another story, but get enough people to use the word in the sense you assign and there you go. That's the way language works.

The corresponding analog to *binary* is [*quinary*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quinary) without a *t*, so if you prefer *quinity* and *quinune*, that would work as well.

Comment: Although "quinune" could be confused for anti-malaria medicine.

Comment: Right. Or a cocktsil mixer. Could  _quinine_ be understood as 5 of 9?

Comment: ... quaternary, quinary, senary, septenary, octonary, nonary, and denary

Comment: @MartinBonner: In common usage, those are all adjectives, but could be substantivized, I suppose.